# How to route between several markers in gmapsfx / JavaFX?

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, routes

how to plot a route between several markers on a map in GMapsFX? I have an application written in Java using JavaFX. There is already implemented map with marked markers. During operation, more markers will be added and it can be generated automatically or, for example, by clicking the button at the end. I've been looking for info on this but couldn't find anything specific. Below is the function that initializes my map.

```
 @Override
 public void mapInitialized() {
  MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();
  mapOptions.mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP).zoom(16).keyboardShortcuts(false);
  map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);
  LatLong latLong = new LatLong(50.0650887,19.9245536);
  MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
  marker = new Marker(markerOptions);
  marker.setPosition(latLong);
  map.addMarker(marker);
  map.setCenter(latLong);
 }
```

Comment: The last time I tried google maps in WebView, or gmapsfx (which relies on google maps in WebView), it did not work.  Google does not support using google maps in WebView.  Once it may have worked, even if unsupported.  Now WebVIew does not provide the functionality required for the current versions of Google Maps to function correctly.

Comment: oh, i understand. If so, can you recommend any other library that I can use in JavaFX to display the map? Where will I be able to display markers and define a route between points?

Comment: No.  Mapping isn't really my field and recommendations aren't on topic for StackOverflow.  There are numerous mapping solutions, you can consider.  For instance, perhaps Bing Maps or some other HTML-based mapping would work in WebView where Google Maps currently doesn't.  Or a Swing-based mapping solution based on OpenStreetMap, like [JMapViewer](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) or maybe something from [ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/openstreetmap-layer/), or something else (you would need to search and evaluate).